# Sign-in with twitter using angular

Tags: angular, twitter-oauth, twitter-login

I am trying to implement singin functioanlity using angular2 , Read from official documentation also [from here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) , But didn't get how the flow is going on. my questions are

1. what are the parameters for accessing first step i.e outh_token ?
2. is there any working example or best articles which teach the flow ?
3. I have read number of questions on SO but none of them work for me.

any suggestion will be appreciated.

PS: as of now i am Hitting Post request on this URL

```
let url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Ftwittercallback&oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key&oauth_nonce=ea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456&oauth_signature=F1Li3tvehgcraF8DMJ7OyxO4w9Y&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1318467427&oauth_version=1.0';
```

But throwing error status code `307`.

also i had tried using **[ng2-twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-twitter)** package but not working.

Comment: Have you got any package working for angular2 with Twitter login?

Comment: not yet @SreejithBS

Comment: which url to redirect to twitter authentication page ? and oauth_token url you can get any examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you use AngularFire2, then you can get it done by just one line and that is

```
logintwitter(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i dont want to use firebase, i need Twitter login without firebase integration

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at great real world example here https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app which uses oauth. I also implemented my sample angular app with full working client/server code to login to Facebook, Linkedin and Google https://github.com/anjmao/adify using ExpressJs and PassportJs.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, in your simple app is there signin with twitter exist ? also in the `real-world` example as you suggested there is nothing for twitter signin process ?

Comment: Not yet, but you can look at https://github.com/anjmao/adify/blob/master/server/src/route/auth.ts#L8 it is very simple to add twitter login, you can use https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter

Comment: i guess you are getting me wrong, i am talking about with angular stuff not with nodejs stuff, we used passport.js with nodejs i think isn't it ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Did you got how to integrate `Twitter OAuth SignIn` in Angular?

Comment: @PardeepJain - We can't use twitter oauth in Angular. In server side NodeJs or PHP, it works perfectly.