# Using Facebook and Google Authentication

Tags: facebook, angular, authentication, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

In my Angular2 app I am using Google, Facebook, Twitter and Github authentication. Twitter works fine. The problem is with Facebook and Google.

1. Facebook: 
   When I enter my username and password for Facebook login, it says `App Not Set Up: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.` whereas while using twitter, the page which should show up on logging in appears.
2. Google: 
   When I am not logged in to any of the mail ids the Google authentication works fine. But if I am already logged in to any of my mail ids, then the authentication system takes that mail id itself and logs in to the app. Is there any way to make it such that the system asks which mail id I want to use, even when I am logged in through one id?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if Twitter working fine in your case you can put some light here https://stackoverflow.com/q/45159463/5043867 ,  in case of Facebook most probably you need to set status of facebook app online this may cause problem

Comment: @PardeepJain could you shed some more light on the facebook bit? And any idea about the google part?

Comment: for facebook you need to set up a app using facebook developer site and then whitelist your app url for the same , and with regard to google you can save your username in the localstorage and then at time of loggin in again delete the local storage and then login again

Comment: @RahulSingh I just use `loginfb() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
  }` For the others I just replace Facebook with Google,Twitter and Github and they work fine. For Facebook where do I place the OAuth redirect URI ?

Comment: i am using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-social-login` not firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force prompt with Google by setting custom parameters. This will give the user the option to switch accounts:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'});
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

Comment: Thanks your code helped. I had to tweak it a bit and make it `this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider().setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'}));` because when I used your exact code, the button wasn't working. But thanks, your code helped. I just reduced it to a line.