# Login with Twitter in Angular 2 package

Tags: angular, twitter

Right now I am working on a Angular2 project. It contains a part like login with Twitter but I have search lot of thing related to it but I did not found any one is suited or working good to the project and also I have look on to the Stack Overflow links as I given.

1. [Login with Twitter in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837348/login-with-twitter-in-angular-2?newreg=b0d93068ce724103b369cc36e6b424a3)
2. [Sign-in with twitter using angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159463/sign-in-with-twitter-using-angular)

But it does not work to me. Could anyone suggest any packages available for this login process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't use this https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/twitter/

Comment: But its a paid one. I'm looking for any open source supportive package

Comment: Why [Sign-in with twitter using angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159463/sign-in-with-twitter-using-angular) does not work for you ?

Comment: look at this one https://github.com/hellotunmbi/angular2-authentication-firebase. It's free. Here is the link for example  : https://angular-auth-firebase.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Twitter does not support client side framework like Angular. You need to have backend for twitter api calls. Use following links for more details and support.
https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Twitters-API-support-CORS
https://twittercommunity.com/